# Where to find Medical data Survival analysis?

Tags: data-request, medical, uses-of-open-data, research, analysis

I have difficulty finding an open-access medical data set with time to an event variable to conduct survival analysis. Where can I find a multivariate data set, preferably with a few hundreds of observations?
Besides those that come with JM R package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Survival Data Sets](http://www.stat.rice.edu/%7Esneeley/STAT553/Datasets/survivaldata.txt)

**Heart transplant data**

Data on 69 patients receiving heart transplants. Taken from "The
Statistical Analysis of Failure Time Data" by Kalbfleisch and Prentice,
Appendix I pages 230-232 from stalib data depository.

- http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/stanford

---

**Ovarian cancer data**

Chemotherapy after surgical treatment. 26 women with minimal residual
the disease was randomized to cyclophosphamide with or without adriamycin.
Survival time in days, status (0 = censored), treatment (2 = combined), age
in years. Example 4.9 in D. Collett, Modelling Survival Data in Medical
Research, Chapman & Hall, 1994 (pg 141)

---

**Cervical cancer data**

Sample of 30 patients from a randomized study of radiotherapy with and without a new radiosensitizer. Based on data from the MRC Working Party on
Advanced Carcinoma of the Cervix, Radiotherapy Oncology 26:93-103, 1993.
Analyzed in and obtained from MKB Parmar, D Machin, Survival Analysis: A
Practical Approach, Wiley, 1995. Group = treatment (2 = radiosensitiser),
age = age in years at diagnosis, status: (0 = censored)
Survival time is in days (from randomization).

---

**Primary Biliary Cirrhosis**

The data set found in appendix D of Fleming and Harrington, Counting
Processes and Survival Analysis, Wiley, 1991. The only differences are:
age is in days
status is coded as 0=censored, 1=censored due to liver tx, 2=death
the sex and stage variables are not missing for obs 313-418

[and more](http://www.stat.rice.edu/%7Esneeley/STAT553/Datasets/survivaldata.txt)